# using vscode as git version (2.31.1) difftool

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, difftool

I installed git version 2.31.1.windows.1
and followed all the necessary steps shown in all git step by step trying to use VSCode as my main difftool, I put these lines in gitconfig files:

```
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = "code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE"
[difftool]
    prompt = true
```

Using the followingsteps:

1. `git config --global diff.tool vscode`
2. `git config --global difftool.vscode.cmd "code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE"`

And even added VSCode to the *PATH* in windows, though I don't have a problem opening the VSCode when running `git config --global -e`, but when I enter the command `git difftool` nothing happens, it just starts a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no diff to display, `git difftool` doesn't open anything -- much like `git diff` returns without outputting any line.

---

There is a known gotcha with `git diff`/`git difftool` : without further arguments, it displays the diff between *what is staged* and your files on disk ; if all of your changes are staged (`git add`ed), then nothing is displayed.

If you want to view *the changes that are staged* compared to your current repo state, run :

```
git diff --cached
# or :
git difftool --cached
```

---

Extra note : a useful option to `git difftool` is `-d` :

```
git difftool -d --cached
git difftool -d <branch1> <branch2>
git difftool -d <anything that can get compared ...>
```

Rather than opening files one by one, it opens your diff viewer in "directory diff" mode.